# Error : Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string laravel 9

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-9

im trying to upload image in laravel but have this error: Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string

this the controller code where i add post to database with the image name:

```
public function create()
    {

        return view('frontoffice.posts.create');
    }
    
    // Store a newly created post in the database
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'content' => 'required',
            'category' => 'required|string',
            
        ]); 
        $file_extensions = $request-> photo -> getClientOriginalExtensions();
        $file_name= time(). '.' .$file_extensions;
        $path = 'images/posts';
        $request -> photo -> move($path,$file_name);
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->user_id = "1";
        $post->content = $request->content;
        $post->category = $request->category;
        $post->likes =  0;
        $post-> photo =    $file_name;
        $post->save();

       

        return redirect()->route('posts.index')->with('success', 'Job created successfully');
    }
```

the blade code where i added the enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form :

```
  <form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            
                    
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                     
                         <input class="form-control" name="photo" type="file" id="photo"> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ul class="d-flex  justify-content-center ">
                        <li><button class="active" type="submit" value="post">Post</button></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('posts.index') }}" title="" >back</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

filesystems:

```
'posts' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => base_path() . 'public/images/posts/',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the error you described isn't related to this one, but you need to add `csrf` protection to your form, since you're using `post` method, because otherwise, the form won't work (you will have 419 page expired error).
So your Blade will be like this

```html
    <form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">

                <input class="form-control" name="photo" type="file" id="photo">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <li><button class="active" type="submit" value="post">Post</button></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route('posts.index') }}" title="">back</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And also you have an error in the function name, it's
`getClientOriginalExtension()` not `getClientOriginalExtensions()`.